# Shorthand to cast a string value

Tags: c#

I'm not talking about javascript, but in javascript, I can declare a `string` like this:

```
var identity = {
    getUserId: function () {
        return 'userid';
    }
};

var userid = identity.getUserId() || '';
```

That means: if `identity.getUserId()` is null or undefined, the value `''` will be casted to `userid` automatically.

Now, in C#:

```
public static void AddOnlineUser(this IIdentity identity)
{
    string userid = identity.GetUserId();

    // long way to check userid is null or not:
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
    {
        userid = "";
    }

    // invalid C# syntax:

    // Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
    // string userid = idenity.GetUserId() || ""; 

    // Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
    // string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid) ? "" : userid;
}
```

I don't mean: `want to create a C# variable same as javascript syntax`. But in this case, is there a way to cast value `""` to `userid` if it's null or empty in 1 line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Null Coalescing Operator `??`**

C# has it's own [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to do this to handle null values :

```
// This will use the available GetUserId() value if available, otherwise the empty string
var userid = identity.GetUserId() ?? "";
```

Keep in mind this operator will only work as expected if the first value in your statement is `null`, otherwise it will use that value. If there is a chance that this isn't the case (and you might encounter a non-null invalid value), then you should consider using a ternary operator instead.

**The Ternary Operator `?:`**

Otherwise, you could use a [ternary operator `?:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (i.e. an inline if-statement) to perform this check as well. This is similar to the example you provided, however it's worth noting that you need to actually set `userid` to the result :

```
// This will set it to empty string if null or empty, otherwise it will use the returned id
userid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(userid) ? "" : userid;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the null-coalescing version described only works if `identity.GetUserId()` returns null, not an empty string in the case where it cannot retrieve the user id.  In this case the result is perfectly fine since it is an empty string either way, but in other scenarios that could lead to very undesired behavior and not match the JavaScript behavior at all.

Comment: Correct on both accounts. I thought I was clarifying that when using the phrase "to handle null values". The ternary approach is probably going to be the closest equivalent to what OP is looking for.